# Module Return Promise to Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an elasticsearch (could be anything though) js file that does a simple query and uses a promise to return the data.

I call that module in my express (server.js) hoping to get the data because eventually I want to send it to angular or whatever really...

Im wondering why I dont get the data back in the express server?

**get.js** *[my elasticsearch js file]*

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200',
});
var Q = require('q')

function GetElastic(qry) {
var deferred = Q.defer();
client.search({
        index: 'social',
        type: 'network',
        body: {
            query: {
                query_string:{
                   query:qry
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {       
        deferred.resolve(resp);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        return deferred.resolve(err);
    });
    return  deferred.promise;
}

module.exports = GetElastic
```

**server.js** *[my express server file]*

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var Get = require('./models/get')

var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/api/posts',function(req, res){
  var qry = 'node'
  var get = new Get(qry)

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(get));
  console.log(get)
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on',3000)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

`var get = new Get(qry)`

to

```
  new Get(qry).then(function(data){
             get  = data;
  });
```